# How can I check the last transaction date for each ClaimNumber and get the value of 1 if its status is 'Open'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

I have a `PolicyNumber` that can have multiple `ClaimNumber`. Same `ClaimNumber` can have different multiple statuses (Open or Closed). I want to pick the  status based on top last `TransactionDate`. And if its 'Open' then in a new column put value of 1. Rest of it should be 0.

```
select  PolicyNumber, 
        ClaimNumber, 
        ClaimantNumber, 
        ReserveStatus, 
        TransactionDate ,
/*  I tried something like this but it doesnt give me correct result */
    CASE 
        WHEN  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber, ClaimNumber ORDER BY TransactionDate desc  )=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as OpenY/N
from RockhillClaimsDataFeed_PBI 
where ClaimNumber = 'CACA0000000117'
order by PolicyNumber
```

The goal is to calculate only open claims.
As you can see an a sample below - out of all `ReserveStatus` I only need 1 where the last top `TransactionDate` is

[image]

EDIT:

Kannan Kandasamy  if I do this query:

```
select  PolicyNumber, 
        ClaimNumber, 
        ClaimantNumber, 
        ReserveStatus, 
        TransactionDate ,
        [Open y/n] = case when ReserveStatus='Open' and Row_number() over(partition by policyNumber, ClaimNumber order by TransactionDate desc) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
from RockhillClaimsDataFeed_PBI 
where ClaimNumber = 'CACA0000000117'
```

Then column `Open y/n` displays all 0
The dates 2/21/2017 would be the correct ones. So I need to grab the ReserveStatus of the one of those dates. The top one. And mark 1 in a column `Open y/n`

[image]

## LONG

Thanks. But I dont have a column `[Open Y/N]` in my dataset.
I modified your query but it says `Incorrect syntax near 'CASE'`

```
WITH ABC
AS
(
select  PolicyNumber, 
        ClaimNumber, 
        ReserveStatus, 
        TransactionDate,
        --[Open Y/N],
        Row_number() over(partition by policyNumber, ClaimNumber order by TransactionDate desc) as Indicator
from RockhillClaimsDataFeed_PBI
)
Update ABC
SET ABC.Indicator = 1 CASE WHEN ABC.ReserveStatus = 'Open' THEN '1' ELSE '0'
WHERE ABC.Indicator = 1
```

Comment: You want this in query results, or an actual update to the table?

Comment: In a query result. If its possible, of course.

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: @Oleg, you missed `End` after the `case when`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_number and get this as below:

```
select  PolicyNumber, 
        ClaimNumber, 
        ClaimantNumber, 
        ReserveStatus, 
        TransactionDate ,
        [Open y/n] = case when ReservceStatus='Open' and Row_number() over(partition by policyNumber, ClaimNumber order by CONVERT(date,TransactionDate) desc) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
from RockhillClaimsDataFeed_PBI
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't take into consideration the status of the row (open / closed) or account for ties, does it?

Comment: #Kannan I have tried your way before, but it doesnt pick up the right result. Probably #Scsimon is correct. But I cant understand how to construct it.

Comment: You can add Status condition to the row_number() condition

Comment: Then clarify your required output

Comment: What is datatype for TransactionDate?

Comment: its varchar . You think that is can be the reason?

Comment: Can you try converting into date, Updated answer accordingly

Comment: @KannanKandasamy  you  were correct. Cant believe this little thing can give me so much trouble. 
Thank you very much for your time and not giving up!!

Comment: Welcome, this query should work, I wondered why it is not... got into interesting problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ABC
AS
(
select  PolicyNumber, 
        ClaimNumber, 
        ReserveStatus, 
        TransactionDate,
        OtherExistingColumn,
        Row_number() over(partition by policyNumber, ClaimNumber order by TransactionDate desc) as Indicator
from RockhillClaimsDataFeed_PBI
)
Update ABC
SET ABC.OtherExistingColumn =  CASE WHEN ABC.ReserveStatus = 'Open' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
WHERE ABC.Indicator = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. But I dont have [Open Y/N] column in my original dataset. Sorry about, I just tried to show how I  want the result set

Comment: @Oleg  I added `End` after `Case when`, did you notice that xD

Comment: Still says the same error. I tried `SELECT` in front of `CASE` but also didnt work.

Comment: @Oleg, checked my edited answer, and the `OtherExistingColumn` should exist in your original table